# Show that this function in a bijection and find the inverse function and fixed points.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given f(x)=(4x+5)mod 15, assuming $N_n \rightarrow N_n$, and thinking of f as a cipher for a alphabet represented by the numbers 0,1.....,n. How would you show f(x)=(4x+5) mod 15 is a bijection, and show any fixed points if any?

Comment: Use the fact that $4 \times 4 = 1 \pmod{15}$. Now, if $f(x) = f(y) \pmod{15}$ then $4x+5 = 4y+5 \pmod{15}$, now can you work with this and get $x = y \pmod{15}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $16x\equiv x$ mod 15, hence $f$ has inverse $g(x)=4(x-5)\equiv 4x-5$ mod $15$. For fixed point we are looking for $x\in\{0,...,15\}$ for which $4x+5\equiv x$ mod $15$, which is the same as saying that $3x+5\equiv 0$ mod $15$. Note that $5, 8, 11, 14$ and $2$ are all not $0$ mod $15$, hence $f$ has no fixed points.

Answer (score 0):

Show g(x) = 4x + 10 (mod 15) is the inverse of f.